# Having an issue with a Google script to autocomplete a Google Doc template from a form submission into a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a Google Form, which submits the responses into a Google Sheet and from that Google Sheet, I've created a script and trigger to then populate a Google Doc template and save the Google Doc to a folder I've created.  As this is my first attempt at Google Scripting, I've tried to copy a video example I found and expanded it to fit my requirements.

I've gone through my script multiple times to try to ensure the variables I've created match the column reference in the Google Sheet as well as the fields I wish to replace in the Google Doc template have the correct names from the variables I created in the script and template.

One note...I have created variables in the script which I do not reference in the script, but I don't know if that is an issue or not.  I wanted to have every column in the Google Sheet tagged to a variable in case I did happen to use it in the future.  Before submitting this, I removed the non-referenced variables and it did not change the outcome, so it seems that's not the issue.  Here's a copy of my script...I have the correct file and folder IDs in the actual script.

```
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var emailAddress = e.values[1];
  var isDate = e.values[2];
  var isTime = e.values[3];
  var ieDate = e.values[4];
  var ieTime = e.values[5];
  var iInj = e.values[6];
  var i18 = e.values[7];
  var fireCalled = e.values[8];
  var lawCalled = e.values[9];
  var medCalled = e.values[10];
  var ecaseNumber = e.values[11];
  var iType = e.values[12];
  var iLocation = e.values[13];
  var cName = e.values[14];
  var cAddress = e.values[15];
  var cCity = e.values[16];
  var cState = e.values[17];
  var cZip = e.values[18];
  var cRace = e.values[19];
  var cSex = e.values[20];
  var cAge = e.values[21];
  var cDOB = e.values[22];
  var cPhone = e.values[23];
  var vName = e.values[24];
  var vAddress = e.values[25];
  var vCity = e.values[26];
  var vState = e.values[27];
  var vZip = e.values[28];
  var vRace = e.values[29];
  var vSex = e.values[30];
  var vAge = e.values[31];
  var vDOB = e.values[32];
  var vPhone = e.values[33];
  var vHeight = e.values[34];
  var vWeight = e.values[35];
  var vHair = e.values[36];
  var vEyes = e.values[37];
  var vPhysical = e.values[38];
  var sName = e.values[39];
  var sAddress = e.values[40];
  var sCity = e.values[41];
  var sState = e.values[42];
  var sZip = e.values[43];
  var sRace = e.values[44];
  var sSex = e.values[45];
  var sAge = e.values[46];
  var sDOB = e.values[47];
  var sPhone = e.values[48];
  var sHeight = e.values[49];
  var sWeight = e.values[50];
  var sHair = e.values[51];
  var sEyes = e.values[52];
  var sPhysical = e.value[53];
  var ve1Answer = e.values[54];
  var ve1Year = e.values[55];
  var ve1Make = e.values[56];
  var ve1Model = e.values[57];
  var ve1Color = e.values[58];
  var ve1TagState = e.values[59];
  var ve1TagNumber = e.values[60];
  var ve1VIN = e.values[61];
  var ve1Desc = e.values[62];
  var ve2Answer = e.values[63];
  var ve2Year = e.values[64];
  var ve2Make = e.values[65];
  var ve2Model = e.values[66];
  var ve2Color = e.values[67];
  var ve2TagState = e.values[68];
  var ve2TagNumber = e.values[69];
  var ve2VIN = e.values[70];
  var ve2Desc = e.values[71];
  var iNarrative = e.values[72];
  var sAnswer = e.values[73];
  var s1Desc = e.values[74];
  var s1Value = e.values[75];
  var s2Desc = e.values[76];
  var s2Value = e.values[77];
  var s3Desc = e.values[78];
  var s3Value = e.values[79];
  var s4Desc = e.values[80];
  var s4Value = e.values[81];
  var s5Desc = e.values[82];
  var s5Value = e.values[83];
  var sTotalValue = e.values[84];
  var dAnswer = e.values[85];
  var d1Desc = e.values[86];
  var d1Value = e.values[87];
  var d2Desc = e.values[88];
  var d2Value = e.values[89];
  var d3Desc = e.values[90];
  var d3Value = e.values[91];
  var d4Desc = e.values[92];
  var d4Value = e.values[93];
  var d5Desc = e.values[94];
  var d5Value = e.values[95];
  var dTotalValue = e.values[96];
  var rAnswer = e.values[97];
  var r1Desc = e.values[98];
  var r1Value = e.values[99];
  var r2Desc = e.values[100];
  var r2Value = e.values[101];
  var r3Desc = e.values[102];
  var r3Value = e.values[103];
  var r4Desc = e.values[104];
  var r4Value = e.values[105];
  var r5Desc = e.values[106];
  var r5Value = e.values[107];
  var rTotalValue = e.values[108];
  var iOfficers = e.values[109];
  var iBadgeNum = e.values[110];
  var iSequenceNum = e.values[111];
  var iCaseNumber = e.values[112];

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById ("REPLACE WITH FILE ID");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("REPLACE WITH FOLDER ID");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(iCaseNumber,templateResponseFolder);

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{INum}}", iCaseNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{ISDate}}", isDate);
  body.replaceText("{{ISTime}}", isTime);
  body.replaceText("{{IEDate}}", ieDate);
  body.replaceText("{{IETime}}", ieTime);
  body.replaceText("{{IInj}}", iInj);
  body.replaceText("{{I18}}", i18);
  body.replaceText("{{IFire}}", fireCalled);
  body.replaceText("{{ILaw}}", lawCalled);
  body.replaceText("{{IMed}}", medCalled);
  body.replaceText("{{ECaseNum}}", ecaseNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{IType}}", iType);
  body.replaceText("{{ILoc}}", iLocation);
  body.replaceText("{{CName}}", cName);
  body.replaceText("{{CAddress}}", cAddress);
  body.replaceText("{{CCity}}", cCity);
  body.replaceText("{{CState}}", cState);
  body.replaceText("{{CZip}}", cZip);
  body.replaceText("{{CRace}}", cRace);
  body.replaceText("{{CSex}}", cSex);
  body.replaceText("{{CAge}}", cAge);
  body.replaceText("{{CDOB}}", cDOB);
  body.replaceText("{{CPhone}}", cPhone);
  body.replaceText("{{VName}}", vName);
  body.replaceText("{{VAddress}}", vAddress);
  body.replaceText("{{VCity}}", vCity);
  body.replaceText("{{VState}}", vState);
  body.replaceText("{{VZip}}", vZip);
  body.replaceText("{{VRace}}", vRace);
  body.replaceText("{{VSex}}", vSex);
  body.replaceText("{{VAge}}", vAge);
  body.replaceText("{{VDOB}}", vDOB);
  body.replaceText("{{VPhone}}", vPhone);
  body.replaceText("{{VHeight}}", vHeight);
  body.replaceText("{{VWeight}}", vWeight);
  body.replaceText("{{VHair}}", vHair);
  body.replaceText("{{VEyes}}", vEyes);
  body.replaceText("{{VPhysical}}", vPhysical);
  body.replaceText("{{SName}}", sName);
  body.replaceText("{{SAddress}}", sAddress);
  body.replaceText("{{SCity}}", sCity);
  body.replaceText("{{SState}}", sState);
  body.replaceText("{{SZip}}", sZip);
  body.replaceText("{{SRace}}", sRace);
  body.replaceText("{{SSex}}", sSex);
  body.replaceText("{{SAge}}", sAge);
  body.replaceText("{{SDOB}}", sDOB);
  body.replaceText("{{SPhone}}", sPhone);
  body.replaceText("{{SHeight}}", sHeight);
  body.replaceText("{{SWeight}}", sWeight);
  body.replaceText("{{SHair}}", sHair);
  body.replaceText("{{SEyes}}", sEyes);
  body.replaceText("{{SPhysical}}", sPhysical);
  body.replaceText("{{V1Year}}", ve1Year);
  body.replaceText("{{V1Make}}", ve1Make);
  body.replaceText("{{V1Model}}", ve1Model);
  body.replaceText("{{V1Color}}", ve1Color);
  body.replaceText("{{V1State}}", ve1TagState);
  body.replaceText("{{V1Num}}", ve1TagNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{V1VIN}}", ve1VIN);
  body.replaceText("{{V1Desc}}", ve1Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{V2Year}}", ve2Year);
  body.replaceText("{{V2Make}}", ve2Make);
  body.replaceText("{{V2Model}}", ve2Model);
  body.replaceText("{{V2Color}}", ve2Color);
  body.replaceText("{{V2State}}", ve2TagState);
  body.replaceText("{{V2Num}}", ve2TagNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{V2VIN}}", ve2VIN);
  body.replaceText("{{V2Desc}}", ve2Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{Narrative}}", iNarrative);
  body.replaceText("{{S1D}}", s1Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{S1V}}", s1Value);
  body.replaceText("{{S2D}}", s2Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{S2V}}", s2Value);
  body.replaceText("{{S3D}}", s3Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{S3V}}", s3Value);
  body.replaceText("{{S4D}}", s4Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{S4V}}", s4Value);
  body.replaceText("{{S5D}}", s5Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{S5V}}", s5Value);
  body.replaceText("{{STV}}", sTotalValue);
  body.replaceText("{{D1D}}", d1Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{D1V}}", d1Value);
  body.replaceText("{{D2D}}", d2Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{D2V}}", d2Value);
  body.replaceText("{{D3D}}", d3Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{D3V}}", d3Value);
  body.replaceText("{{D4D}}", d4Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{D4V}}", d4Value);
  body.replaceText("{{D5D}}", d5Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{D5V}}", d5Value);
  body.replaceText("{{DTV}}", dTotalValue);
  body.replaceText("{{R1D}}", r1Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{R1V}}", r1Value);
  body.replaceText("{{R2D}}", r2Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{R2V}}", r2Value);
  body.replaceText("{{R3D}}", r3Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{R3V}}", r3Value);
  body.replaceText("{{R4D}}", r4Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{R4V}}", r4Value);
  body.replaceText("{{R5D}}", r5Desc);
  body.replaceText("{{R5V}}", r5Value);
  body.replaceText("{{RTV}}", rTotalValue);
  body.replaceText("{{ROs}}", iOfficers);
  body.replaceText("{{ROBs}}", iBadgeNum);
  body.replaceText("{{TimeStamp}}", timestamp);
    
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

And here's the trigger I've created for the function...

[Script Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHVUS.jpg)

EXPECT: I enter data into the Google Form, the form should then enter the data into a Google Sheet and trigger the script to populate the Google Doc template from the fields in the Google Sheet and save the Google Doc in a folder I've created.

CURRENT RESULTS: I enter data into the Google Form, the data is sent to the Google Sheet, but the Google Doc is not populated and saved to the directory.  After submitting the form, I'm sent an email with the following error message.

Start / 2023-04-06 11:56:27 Eastern Daylight Time

Function / autoFillGoogleDocFromForm

Error Message / TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '53')   formSubmit

Trigger End / 2023-04-06 11:56:28 Eastern Daylight Time

I've tried to research that error message and code, but have been unable to find any information on it.  Again, this is my first attempt at Google scripting, so I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake...any insight is very much appreciated!

Comment: I've found another post saying I should modify the variables to allow for a null value, so I've modified all of the variables to include the following   var timestamp = e.values[0] || "";  but this did not change the outcome

Comment: Your form has 111 entries required?  Boy I wouldn't want to have to fill in that form.

Comment: My point is, is your form really 111 questions, or do you fill in additional columns manually or by formulas?  Let say your form is only 53 questions (index 52) then `e.value.[53]` is undefined.

Comment: Further to @TheWizEd 's comment, have you done any troubleshooting such as creating just the first five (or 10, 20, or 53!) variables and running `replaceText` with just those placeholders. Make sure the basics of your script are working and drill down to the error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The form really is 111 questions as it is an incident report for the security team here so there's many options for the security team to detail in the event of an incident.  My next step tomorow was to start over and just build a small template instead in order to test the basics of the form/sheet/doc functionality, but I just wanted to see if there was some sort of obvious rookie mistake in how I set up the function and other parameters.

Comment: Would the var timestamp = e.values[0] || "";  resolve a null value issue?  I read about that variation of the variable parameter in another post, but wasn't sure if it would actually keep the script from bombing out if the form did have an empty value because that *could* happen.  Every field has the potential of being filled in, but every field *is not* mandatory.

Comment: I went back and reentered a section at a time and now it's working as expected.  Related question...I was hoping to create a incident number by concatenating a sequential number with the YYYYMM from the timestamp.  I can create array formulas in the Google Sheet for those and it will populate the fields as each new record is entered from the form, but it's not picking that value up from the Google sheet and putting it into the template.  My assumption is since that data is not created from the form itself, it won't be able to take it from the sheet to populate the template...is that correct?

Comment: I'm sorry; I was ignoring you. I only noticed your comments today. FYI: `With the "@reply" feature, Stack Overflow allows you to notify users directly by typing the user's name preceded by the "@" symbol (for example: @rsmith). This will create a notification in that user's global inbox.`